# This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable. Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbcontext

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace SqlEFTester {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            ConnectionManager connectionManager = new ConnectionManager();
            SqlConnection conn = connectionManager.Connection;
            conn.Open();

            //BEGIN TRAN
            SqlTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction();

            //Will do some legacy work using SqlTransaction, so can not use TransactionScope here.

            MyContext context = new MyContext(conn);
            List<Inventory> list = context.Inventories.Take(10).ToList();//Just get top 10 Inventories

            //COMIT TRAN
            tran.Commit();

            Console.WriteLine("Done...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

class ConnectionManager {
    public SqlConnection Connection {
        get {
            return new SqlConnection("Data Source=MYSERVER;Initial Catalog=MYDATABASE;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
        }
    }
}

[Table("Inventory")]
class Inventory {
    [Key]
    public int InventoryId { get; set; }
}

class MyContext : DbContext {
    public EmutContext(SqlConnection conn)
        : base(conn, false) {
        //I have to close it, otherwise it will say "EntityConnection can only be constructed with a closed DbConnection."
            base.Database.Connection.Close();
    }

    public DbSet<Inventory> Inventories { get; set; }
}
```

What I am trying to do is execute EF code inside traditional ADO.NET `SqlTransaction`.

I open a connection and pass the same connection to EF to reuse the connection. By design, I have to close the connection since its complaining

> EntityConnection can only be constructed with a closed DbConnection.

If I run above code I got

> Transaction has completed.

I can not commit. NOTE: I can not use `TransactionScope` because of legacy code framework we use.

Comment: Do you tried creating EmutContext before you called conn.Open? In your code you close connection and this will finish your transaction, this way transaction will be closed before commit.

Comment: If I move context creation just before conn.Open() then I got this "EntityConnection can only be constructed with a closed DbConnection." I move code line this ConnectionManager      connectionManager = new ConnectionManager();
            SqlConnection conn = connectionManager.Connection;
            MyContext context = new MyContext(conn);
            conn.Open();

Answer (score 3):

Well, I would better use TransactionScope, but as a workaround you can try to use reflection (maybe there are a better way, not sure). Please note that I am passing closed SqlConnection to context, then open EntityConnection (this will open SqlConnection)

```
        //create connection & context
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("your connection");
        YourDbContext context = new YourDbContext(sqlConnection, false);

        var entityConnection = (EntityConnection)((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.Connection;
        try
        {
            //open entity connection - will open store connection
            entityConnection.Open();

            var entityTransaction = entityConnection.BeginTransaction();

            //get sql transaction via reflection
            var sqlTransaction = (SqlTransaction)entityTransaction.GetType()
                                                      .InvokeMember("StoreTransaction",
                                                                    BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod
                                                                    | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, entityTransaction, new object[0]);



            //here you got both sql transaction & sql connectont
            var cmd = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.Transaction = sqlTransaction;
            cmd.CommandText = "your sql statement";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //do your context work - will be in entity transaction

            //invoke save changes
            context.SaveChanges();

            entityTransaction.Commit();
        }
        finally
        {
            entityConnection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Would something like this work instead of using reflection: ((IDbCommand)cmd).Transaction = conn.BeginTransaction(); ?

Comment: @Pawel If you will create SqlTransaction in this way, unfortunatelly any queries you run with EntityConnection (e.g. any context queries, including linq queries mentioned by author) will not use this transaction. If you need to run both context queries and raw sql within same transaction, you need to use TransactionScope. Author mentioned that he can't use TransactionScope,  so I wrote this small sample how to retrieve SqlTransaction from EntityTransaction, this will also allow to run context queries + raw sql within same transaction. I do not like this method myself because of reflection.