# How does Entity Framework convert an EntityTransaction into a provider specific transaction?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I've got an Entity Framework 4 data mode.  I'm loading data into a database using stored procedures since EF is so slow.  We use the entity model to call the stored procedures.  Everything has to be in one transaction.

In order to speed up the process, I need to perform some bulk copy operations.  I'm using SQL Anywhere and their ADO.NET provider software for this.

When I call `context.Connection.BeginTransactin()`, I get an `EntityTransaction` back.  Actually, my variable is a `DbTransaction`, which is the base class for all transactions.  But the actual object returned is an `EntityTransaction`.

I can't cast an `EntityTransaction` into the provider specific transaction class (`SAConnection` in this case).  If I do, I get a cast exception.  Yet, somehow, when the entity context calls the stored procedures, it's enlisting the provider specific command objects it creates into the transaction represented by that `EntityTransaction` object.

How does the provider do this?  Is it a mechanism I can use to get a provider-specific transaction object for my bulk copy operations?

Tony

Comment: Fyi, according to [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entitytransaction.aspx) wraps the provider specific transaction (see remarks). Unlike other Entity Framework classes (like EntityConnection, which provides Access to the original Connection via the StoreConnection property) this class does not expose the wrapped instance. You might be able to get a reference to it using reflection to gain access to a possibly private member which holds the original transaction. Let me know, if this is suitable for you, and i'll try to help you out with some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken a look at the `EntityTransaction` class and in fact an internal property called `StoreTransaction` exists. If found some source-code in this SO discussion: [This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable. Entity Framework Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843449/this-sqltransaction-has-completed-it-is-no-longer-usable-entity-framework-code) which might help you out.

Keep in mind, that this won't work in partial trust environments, which do not allow you to access members using reflection.

Comment: J. Tihon:  Thanks!  I'll try the reflection code and see if it works for us.  It would be better, however, if Microsoft made that member public.  There are cases where people have no choice but to combine ADO.NET objects with entity framework and using a TransactionScope is not possible.